Installing ubuntu broke my battery
I have installed Ubuntu a few months ago, a few days/weeks later i started noticing my battery started charging poorly, since it charged bad on Windows and Ubuntu, i thought it was a hardware problem. I had it repared in the store and they did a factory reset too. Today I reinstalled Ubuntu and immediately noticed the batteryproblem happening again. I just deleted Ubuntu and did a factory reset but the issues keep happening.
My laptop is a Samsung NP750XED and after installing it I edited the files mentionned here since I had the same bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2045072
I used to have ZorinOS light installed which worked fine (but also had that bug)
In summery: my battery drains even when it's charging and I do nothing on it, this happened since installing ubuntu twice now. How can I fix this?
If there is anything else you need to know please ask me.

Not an Ubuntu issue as you proved when you had same issue with other OS s. You have a hardware problem take it to a better repair shop or back to the maker is my suggestion. Not on topic for this site.

It went back to the factory of Samsung themselves, and to me it seems like an ubuntu problem since ubuntu caused it

Does your battery also charge poorly in Windows, or does it just charge poorly in Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based derivatives?

It also charges poorly in Windows.
